# gulp-imagemin task run gives error

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-imagemin, pngcrush

I am trying to compress my images for the production server but getting an error in running the `gulp-imagemin` task.

This is my gulp task:

```
gulp.task('images', function(){
    gulp.src('builds/development/images/**/*.*')
    .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', imageMin({
        progressive:true,
        svgoPlugins:[{removeViewBox:false}],
        use:[pngCrush()]
    })))
    .pipe(gulpif(env === 'production', gulp.dest('builds/production/images')))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

I am getting the following trace:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: spawn UNKNOWN
  at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
  at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:298:11)
  at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
  at ret.catch.module.exports.promise (C:\Users\user\desktop\workflows\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-jpegtran\node_modules\exec-buffer\node_modules\execa\index.js:139:26)
  at C:\Users\user\desktop\workflows\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-jpegtran\node_modules\exec-buffer\index.js:35:15
```

Can someone please have a look and try to provide some solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try running without the parameters in imageMin first. from there I suggest you start adding one by one to spot out which plugin is breaking.  If you are looking for image compression I suggest gulp-tinypng-compress, best

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a production server and I've tried:

- Running `imagemin` without parameters;
- Checking all possible permission issues;
- Changing node version to latest;

The solution was to delete the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again. 
Strangely enough, it worked as a charm!